# HP LeftHand StoreVirtual VSA host affinity

Tags: vmware-esxi, storage-area-network

I am testing the HP LeftHand StoreVirtual VSA for ESXi 5.x (a 3 nodes setup, hosting the VMs in the same hosts that have the VSA appliances).

Is there a way to define some sort of 'ESXi host to VSA node affinity'?

I setup the Cluster iSCSI Virtual IP, and that seems to just round-robin the nodes.

I believe that it would be more efficient if each host connected to their own node (unless it is down of course)...

Comment: Do you have DRS? If so, you can look into creating affinity/anti-affinity rules, although I'm not sure how well that would work with your VSA's.

Comment: @joeqwerty: I do not have DRS as of this moment, however, I believe that is a higher level. Isn't DRS to dynamically adjust the allocation of VMs to datastores? (I only have a single datastore, stripped in 3 nodes in VSA). I could create many datastores, but it is the same issue. I want to "prioritize" the path used by each host.